Linebreak in Json php
i'm using follow code to send a messages to gateway sms.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://urlgateway');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"message\": \"Hi, ". "This is the message\",
\"phoneNumbers\": [\"phone sender\", \"phone target\"] }");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username' . ':' . 'password');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

As you can see message is single line " Hi, This is a test message"
how can i break the line for ex.
"Hi,<br>
This is the message"

i'd try to add \n but get error about json parse body..
someone can help?
thanks

If you get an error, always tell us the exact error message and what threw it

Don't build your JSON by hand. Instead use an object or an array and call json_encode on that. https://3v4l.org/2URQD

@ADyson Adding \n inside bracket i get console error :
main.js?ver=3.3.3:2 {"message":"can't parse body: invalid character '\n' in string literal"}

I think you should consult the vendor.

@Fabio Thanks. As Chris Haas said, you should build your JSON using the correct tools - that's guaranteed to produce valid JSON and not introduce accidental syntax / escaping problems. Try that, I would expect it's very likely to solve your issue. e.g. https://3v4l.org/p35Gd

@ADyson, as your advice, the \n string is wrote as text in message..  "Hi, \nThis is the message" .. it not works as brakeline.

BTW i guess its solved. just wrote message using shift+return keypress , in the var.

Well we have ruled out your side as the problem, if you've properly JSON-encoded the data as per those 3v4l demos. So if it's still not working with the newline character you should think of contacting the SMS vendor about how they expect you to do it. But if you did find a solution, which it sounds like you did, then please post an Answer below in the box, so the community can find it in searches, and vote on it - see also [answer]

Solved, thanks who helped me..
btw , solution is simple..
just write var with formatted text.. using (shift+return) on the keyboard.
$data = [ 'message' => 'Hi,
This is the row1,
this is the row 2,
(shift+return) on each line,
',];

